# Selenium + browsermob-proxy: creating new HAR on redirected pages

Tags: javascript, selenium, redirect, browsermob-proxy

I've got a next use case for combination of `Selenium` and `browsermob-proxy`:

- for initial page access new Har is created
- initial request can be redirected (multiple times)
- and then redirected again by JavaScript

E.g.
**Page A ---> 302 redirect** to **Page B ---> 200** and then **JS redirect to Page C**

**Is it possible to create a new Har on each redirect (either server or JS).
So a Har should exist for each page and its resources.**

Answer (score 0):

I have been using some browsermob on one redirect that opens in a new window/tab. I have noticed that in my case you must switch windows to continue recording traffic for the Har. I did not create a new Har.